# WCF XmlElement serialization/deserialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, deserialization

Have a WCF service, which has a DataMember with custom nodes (names and numbers of items may be different)
Example:

```
<AppData>
 <sometag>something</sometag>
 <othertag>something else</othertag>
</AppData>
```

Member definition as:

```
  <DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>
  Public AppData As  XmlElement
```

it's working only for one item.

Definition like:

```
  <DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>
  Public AppData As List(Of XmlElement)
```

wrapped inner tags in class name tag:

```
<AppData>
 <XmlElement><sometag>something</sometag></XmlElement>
 <XmlElement><othertag>something else</othertag></XmlElement>
</AppData>
```

Comment: The solution for me was using <XmlAnyElement> attribute:

    <XmlAnyElement()> 
    Public AppData As XmlElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `AppData` as an `XElement` - then when you are ready to send the data just create a new `XElement` passing the list to it - it will create a parent with many child elements one for each `XElemen`t in the list. The constructor for `XElemen`t is `IEnumerable<XElement>` aware

Answer (score 1):

Since your XML data blob has a root element called `<AppData>`, and the WCF data member that contains it is also called `AppData`, then that *implies* that the serialised message should have two nested elements, thus:

```
<AppData> <!-- this maps to the WCF DataMember field -->
    <AppData> <!-- this is the root element of your blob -->
        <sometag>something</sometag>
        <othertag>something else</othertag>
    </AppData>
</AppData>
```

With what you have at the moment, the deserialiser is seeing the one `<AppData>` element, and assuming that it is the WCF data member `Public AppData As XmlElement`. It then looks inside that element and finds two child elements, `<sometag>` and `<othertag>`. However, it has only been told to look for one element (`XmlElement`), so it ignores the second one.

You should look at changing either the schema of your XML blob, or the WCF data contract member that contains it.

Comment: Big thanks for your answer, i found a solution: it's <XmlAnyElement> attribute for type definition.